# PHP Sitemap Function

Tags: php, mysql

As per usual I have spent the past few hours on this but cannot work out a better way. I have a CMS and need to create a sitemap. I have a function of the works but is messy and not really fit for purpose and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. I under there are for loops and the likes but I'm not all that use how to use them yet. I have included the function I already have as well as a demo of the database.

tbl_website_posts

```
| ID  | Title             | Parent ID |
|-----|-------------------|-----------|
| 1   | Parent 1          | 0         |
| 2   | Parent 2          | 0         |
| 3   | Child of 2        | 2         |
```

Functions.php

```
function generate_sitemap($site_id) {
    global $dbcon;
    $return = '<ul>';
    $icon = array('page' => 'fa-file-word', 'post' => 'fa-newspaper', 'event' => 'fa-calendar-star', 'calander' => 'fa-calendar-alt', 'training' => 'fa-award', 'people' => 'fa-user-alt', 'group' => 'fa-users-class');
    $query_1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='0'");
    while ($array_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $parent_id_1 = $array_1['id'];
        $query_2 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_1'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_2) > 0) {
            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_1['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_1['post_title'];
            $return .= '<ul>';
            while ($array_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $parent_id_2 = $array_2['id'];
                $query_3 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_2'");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_3) > 0) {
                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_2['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_2['post_title'];
                    $return .= '<ul>';
                    while ($array_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        $parent_id_3 = $array_3['id'];
                        $query_4 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_3'");
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_4) > 0) {
                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_3['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_3['post_title'];
                            $return .= '<ul>';
                            while ($array_4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                $parent_id_4 = $array_4['id'];
                                $query_5 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_4'");
                                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_5) > 0) {
                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_4['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_4['post_title'];
                                    $return .= '<ul>';
                                    while ($array_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_5, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                        $parent_id_5 = $array_5['id'];
                                        $query_6 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_5'");
                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_6) > 0) {
                                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_5['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_5['post_title'];
                                            $return .= '<ul>';
                                            while ($array_6 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_6, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                $parent_id_6 = $array_6['id'];
                                                $query_7 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_6'");
                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_7) > 0) {
                                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_6['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_6['post_title'];
                                                    $return .= '<ul>';
                                                    while ($array_7 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_7, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                        $parent_id_7 = $array_7['id'];
                                                        $query_8 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_7'");
                                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_8) > 0) {
                                                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_7['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_7['post_title'];
                                                            $return .= '<ul>';
                                                            while ($array_8 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_8, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                                $parent_id_8 = $array_8['id'];
                                                                $query_9 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_8'");
                                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_9) > 0) {
                                                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_8['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_8['post_title'];
                                                                    $return .= '<ul>';
                                                                    while ($array_9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                                        $parent_id_9 = $array_9['id'];
                                                                        $query_10 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_9'");
                                                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_10) > 0) {
                                                                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_9['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_9['post_title'];
                                                                            $return .= '<ul>';
                                                                            while ($array_10 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_10, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                                                $parent_id_10 = $array_10['id'];
                                                                                $query_11 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_10'");
                                                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_11) > 0) {
                                                                                    $return .= '<li>' . $array_10['post_title'];
                                                                                    $return .= '<ul>';
                                                                                    while ($array_11 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_11, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                                                        $parent_id_11 = $array_11['id'];
                                                                                        $query_12 = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id_11'");
                                                                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_12) > 0) {
                                                                                            $return .= '<li>' . $array_11['post_title'];
                                                                                            $return .= '<ul>';
                                                                                            while ($array_12 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_12, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                                                                $return .= '<li>' . $array_12['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            $return .= '</ul>';
                                                                                            $return .= '</li>';
                                                                                        } else {
                                                                                            $return .= '<li>' . $array_11['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    } 
                                                                                    $return .= '</ul>';
                                                                                    $return .= '</li>';
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    $return .= '<li>' . $array_10['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                                                }
                                                                            } 
                                                                            $return .= '</ul>';
                                                                            $return .= '</li>';
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            $return .= '<li>' . $array_9['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                                        }
                                                                    } 
                                                                    $return .= '</ul>';
                                                                    $return .= '</li>';
                                                                } else {
                                                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_8['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_8['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                                }
                                                            } 
                                                            $return .= '</ul>';
                                                            $return .= '</li>';
                                                        } else {
                                                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_7['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_7['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                        }
                                                    } 
                                                    $return .= '</ul>';
                                                    $return .= '</li>';
                                                } else {
                                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_6['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_6['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                                }
                                            } 
                                            $return .= '</ul>';
                                            $return .= '</li>';
                                        } else {
                                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_5['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_5['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    $return .= '</ul>';
                                    $return .= '</li>';
                                } else {
                                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_4['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_4['post_title'] . '</li>';
                                }
                            } 
                            $return .= '</ul>';
                            $return .= '</li>';
                        } else {
                            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_3['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_3['post_title'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    } 
                    $return .= '</ul>';
                    $return .= '</li>';
                } else {
                    $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_2['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_2['post_title'] . '</li>';
                }
            } 
            $return .= '</ul>';
            $return .= '</li>';
        } else {
            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array_1['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array_1['post_title'] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $return .= '</ul>'; 
    return $return;
}
```

The function is also very limited to only going so many children in. If anyone has and suggestions on where I could start that would be amazing. Thank you in advance for your time.

Alan.

Comment: ...wow :-) that's an impressive _arrow (anti) pattern_ :-)

Comment: Just looking at this code gives me vertigo.

Comment: Thanks, that's why I need some help to fix it xD, unfortunately, someone decided to downvote so lost basically all the rep I had I hate how this site does that...

Comment: @AlanTiller what you might need is a recursive function.

Comment: Ok Zedfoxus I'll go do some research, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a recursive function for this.

**Disclaimer**: this is untested code I wrote in the StackOverflow editor, but it looks legit to me. YMMV, use it mostly for inspiration :-)

```
function generate_sitemap($site_id, $parent_id=0) {
    global $dbcon;
    $return = '';

    $query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM tbl_website_posts WHERE post_website='$site_id' AND post_parent='$parent_id'");

    // side note: once you get this working it will be worth the effort to turn
    // this query into a prepared statement. Using variables in your query like
    // this puts you at risk of a SQL injection attack.

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $return = '<ul>';
        $icon = array('page' => 'fa-file-word', 'post' => 'fa-newspaper', 'event' => 'fa-calendar-star', 'calander' => 'fa-calendar-alt', 'training' => 'fa-award', 'people' => 'fa-user-alt', 'group' => 'fa-users-class');

        while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $return .= '<li data-jstree=\'{"icon":"fal ' . $icon[$array['post_type']] . '"}\'>' . $array['post_title'];

            $return .= generate_sitemap($site_id, $array['id']);

            $return .= '</li>';
        }

        $return .= '</ul>'; 
    }

    return $return;
}
```

So basically, start out assuming the parent won't have any child pages (initial `$return` value is an empty string, so we don't return an empty `<ul></ul>`).

Only if there are children, start building the `<ul>` with all child pages.

Inside the `<li>` for a child page, have the function call itself with the child's id as the new parent id. If the child has no child pages, the nested function call will return an empty string. Otherwise, it will return a `<ul>` with all of its children.

Comment: Neat! It's commendable that you whipped up code in the SO answer window. Yeah, OP will need some kind of recursion.

Comment: Just had a go at trying to get this working but my server error_log came back with "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted" I turned off the memory limit but it just 503's and idea why?

Comment: Could be that you created a never-ending recursion. Are you sure you're sending a different parent id (second argument) to the function from the nested call?

Comment: @rickdenhaan you're completly right I overlooked the fact that items with no parent will have 0 creating an infinite loop!

Comment: There you go, sounds like a reasonably straight-forward if-statement to add :-)

Comment: Thank you all so much, it works perfectly. I can't believe it was that simple but have definitely learned something new today!

Comment: If you've never dealt with recursion before it can take a while to wrap your head around the concept. Glad to be of help!

Comment: I'm not sure that I support recursive trips to the db.  There are some scenarios where this is inadvisable.  Separately, using prepared statements would be a solid idea.

Comment: @mickmackusa Can you be more specific as to why this particular usage (building a site map) would be inadvisable? I suppose an alternative solution would be to execute one query to retrieve all pages into a PHP array, optionally grouped by parent_id, and then recursively iterate over that. But that's a lot of extra steps that may not be necessary.

Comment: I don't know what volume of data is at play here.  I only mean to give a caution about the expense of recursive trips to the db.  If there is a max depth of 10 to this recursion, maybe a single verbose query would be best.

Comment: Just spitballing... perhaps successive subqueries that use IN to qualify the next set of relatives.  This way, there is only one trip to the db.

Comment: That will only work if you know ahead of time how deep the nesting goes. Unless you use a recursive stored procedure. There's an idea. Of course, that doesn't answer the OP's original question, which I interpreted as basically: how do I go from this nested mess of for-loops to something more manageable :)